# What does the slang "My eye!" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

Does the slang **my eye** in following sentence represent "Surprise" or sadness?

> I heard that you made a high jump of eight feet at the track meet. My eye!

From the paragraph above, I understand that the speaker was surprised/shocked or unhappy  to know his friend made that high jump.

Please correct me.

Comment: It means the speaker is stuck in some kind of pre-WW2 linguistic timewarp. I don't think I've *ever* heard anyone use this expression "for real" in 50 years.

Comment: "My eye!"  indicates doubt.  Said to be originally nautical slang.  (Don't believe Fumblefingers.  He is stuck on some backwater island.)

Comment: Hmm...an enigma! In another example of how we are adversaries with those closeest to us, [the French have almost the identical situation re eye, foot, ass](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/common-usage-of-mon-%C5%93il). Now who stole from who, and where did the original come from?

Comment: @GEdgar Which island appears to be at least 25 years behind the rest of the world.

Comment: @GEdgar, deadrat, FumbleFingers: We're all talking about Newfoundland, right?

Comment: [D'origine français?](http://www.notrefamille.com/dictionnaire/expressions/mon_oeil):'Elle découlerait d'une autre expression de la fin du XIXe siècle "il n'y a pas plus que mon œil". Le sens en est que si l'œil ne le voit pas, c'est que ça n'est pas prouvé.' Pretty obvious, non? ('It follows from another expression of the late nineteenth century "there is no more than my eye." The sense is that if the eye does not see, then it is not proven.'

Comment: I do wonder if it was derived from the earlier "My eye and Betty Martin", a Cockney exclamation, said to derive from "Oh mihi, beate Martine", the opening of a Roman Catholic Latin prayer to St Martin. I'll do some more research, if I get time.

Comment: For more current expressions of surprise/shock containing "my," there's "My word" and "[Oh] my stars."

Comment: There is also "...in a pig's eye"

Comment: It's really a slightly obfuscated way of saying, "You're a liar." and I always thought it meant, "You can take my eye if that turns out to be true." (Also, while I haven't heard it recently where I currently live, it's definitely been in "actual" use less that 50 years ago- I think it's still in use in some of the Southern US states.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**My eye**

> Like hell, that's nonsense, as in *You were at the library all day? My eye, you were!*
>
> This slangy expression of disbelief was first recorded in 1842. From about 1800 to the 1930s the same term was used to indicate surprise ( My eye, she's been promoted after all.) but this usage seems to be obsolete.

[The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/my+eye)

Therefore, in your sentence, the speaker is bemused by the claim.

More like the colloquial - My a** you made a jump that high!

Comment: You mean "my ass"? +1)

Comment: So my eye means non-sense? Speaker did not belive if his friend could make that hight jump, so he said My eye! am I right here?

Comment: @Starkeen - Yes. "My eye" is used for expressing disbelief by making a mockery of the (improbable)claims.

Comment: @Rathony - ya! Don't we need to censor out expletives?! ;)

Comment: almost identical in meaning to "my foot": http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/my+foot

Comment: Who says *ass* is an expletive? My eye. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. "My eye, if you want me to go with you to the market" is it ok to use the slang at starting of the sentence?

Comment: I tried to search for related examples but couldn't find one. Perhaps, "My eye you want me to go to the market with you" should be fine. Although I personally prefer *my eye* at the end of the sentence.
*You want me to go to the market with you? My eye you want to!!*

Comment: surprisingly enough, the exact same expression exists in french.

Comment: Though this is just guessing on my part, *My eye*, in a sentence, might be more literally translated like, "*You were at the library all day? [I'd give] My eye, [if] you were!*" meaning they don't believe it to the extent that they would gamble their eye on it.